# Change working drive

Tags: vba, excel

I have some standardized processes in my macros to apply changes to a bunch of files placed in any directory, and I don't know why I get different results. To illustrate, this is the beginning of the standard code:

```
'list files in the folder where this macro is placed
strNombreCarpeta = ThisWorkbook.Path
ChDir strNombreCarpeta
strArchivoExcel = Dir("*." & CStr(strExtension))

'rest of the code
```

Even if my working directory is in another drive (not "C:"), I can get the for 'strNombreCarpeta' variable, content as 'E:/updating/12_06_files/' and process the files on that folder.

But, working with the same macro file in another PC, that process simply doesn't work, the variable 'strNombreCarpeta' gets a null value, and, the "Dir" command works as is my default path was %CURRENT_USER%/DOCUMENTS and tries to list the files on that folder.

So, I don't get any changes in the files I want.

Some idea why this change of drive works only sometimes?
How can I prevent that?

Working always in "C:" is not a standard solution, because the space in drive is limited.

Comment: You don't need ChDir or ChDrv if you always pass the full path to Dir()

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Path` cannot return a NULL value. It will return a empty String `""` if the workbook is not saved until now. This will occur if the workbook is created from a template (`*.xltm`). If double clicked this template a new unsaved workbook is opened. Or someone had used the `*.xlsm` as a template by right clicking it and choosing `New` instead of `Open`. So how is the workbook opened?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge ChDir cannot change CurrentDrive. You have to use seperate command - ChDrive. So the code would look like:

```
strNombreCarpeta = thisworkbook.path
strDrive = left(strNombreCarpeta,1)
ChDrive strDrive
ChDir strNombreCarpeta

strArchivoExcel = Dir("*." & CStr(strExtension))
```

Personally I would just use full folder directory with Dir function. So:

```
strArchivoExcel = Dir(strNombreCarpeta & "\*." & CStr(strExtension))
```

This is easier and safer in my opinion. It might even work on network paths (UNC)

If someone nows the answer why it sometimes work without ChDrive, I would like to know the anwser myself. My best working theory is that some other process is changing application.CurrDrive & .CurrDir.

CAUTION: I didn't test any code above - I don't have Office installed on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of more reliable ways to get the list of files without using `ChDir`:

```
Public Sub listFilesDir()
    Dim f As Variant

    f = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "*.txt")

    Do While Len(f) > 0
        Debug.Print f
        f = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub listFilesFSO()
    Dim fso As Object, fsoFolder As Object, f As Variant

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)


    For Each f In fsoFolder.Files
        If InStr(f.Name, ".txt") > 0 Then Debug.Print f.Name
    Next

    'or

    For Each f In fsoFolder.Files
        If f.Type = "Text Document" Then Debug.Print f.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

---

- `.xlsm Type: "Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet"`
- `.csv  Type: "Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File"`
- `.txt  Type: "Text Document"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. Yep, ThisWorkbook.Path is not null, strNombreCarpeta gets a value, actually, ChDir is what wasn't working.

I thing I found the solution in the Windows system. My PC has everything installed in drive 'C:' (Windows, Program Files, Users) but the little difference is that I MOVED 'Documents', 'Images' and 'Downloads' subfolders to drive 'E:'. So, the macro process starts in 'E:' from the beginning and that's the reason why ChDir works apropiately to 'E:/updating/12_06_files/'.

Surprisingly, trying to run the macro in my own PC in a folder like 'C:/updating/' shows the same error that I got at other PCs.

I made a little modification to my code adding these lines:

```
strCurrentDrive = Left(ThisWorkbook.Path,2)
ChDrive strCurrentDrive
ChDir strNombreCarpeta 
'rest of the code
```

and worked! I'm not sure if would there be a difference at some point between using 'Left(ThisWorkbook.Path,2)' or 'Left(ThisWorkbook.Path,1)' but both of them works.

I have used 'fso' before to count files in folders, but I prefer to avoid it, usually makes the process a little slow.

Thanks again to everybody.